# Facebook application iframe php

Tags: php, facebook

Please excuse me for being thick (or not) but does a FaceBook iframe (canvas) application "behave" like any other iframe on a website? - OK I'll accept you need access to the api etc with the keys, but once that is achieved am I being totally off the wall in thinking that a FB iframe application "just" runs the relevant app. pages in an iframe, exactly the same way that any other site does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are correct.  Facebook does post some information through the iFrame to enable different parts of the JS library that you should load with the page to access their features.  But in essance, they are loading an iFrame of a website and displaying it inside of their wrapper.  Also it is very different than an FBML app because it is rendered on your server and then the rendered content is sent to the iFrame rather than the FBML being rendered by FB then displayed on the screen.

Comment: thanks for that it's what I assumed but FB docs are not exactly "the best" when it comes to clarity ... makes my live "much" easier - phew.

Comment: I totally agree.  My first Facebook app took so much digging for answers online because the FB documentation always left you asking for more clarity.  I think all the documentation was written by frustrated programmers who wanted to pass a bit of frustration on to the end user.